# Colors not changing when button is pressed P5.JS package

Tags: javascript, colors, drawing, p5.js

So I'm making a paint program for my computer science class in JavaScript using the p5.js package. However when changing colors between white and black, and red and black the black paint color stays red. 
I've tried checking if the red, white and black, buttons are somehow tied to each other but it dosen't seem to me that they are. Here's a Repl.it if you want to try it out; https://repl.it/join/sarfsozb-aidendombrosky1
Here's the code

```js
var sR = 0
var sG = 0
var sB = 0

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    background(255);
}

function draw() {
    //pallete buffer
    strokeWeight(1);
    stroke(0);
    fill(255);
    rect(0,0, 60, 600);
    stroke(0)
    strokeWeight(1)
    //red 
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    //green
    fill(0,255,0);
    rect(0,50,50,50);
    //blue
    fill(0,0,255);
    rect(0,100,50,50);
    //ereaser
    fill(255)
    rect(0,150,50,50); 
    //black
    fill(0);
    rect(0,200,50,50)

    // Buttons 
    //red button
    if (mouseIsPressed && mouseX > 0 && mouseX < 50 && mouseY > 0 && mouseY < 50) {
        sR = 255
        sG = 0
        sB = 0 
    } 

      //blue Button
    else if (mouseIsPressed && mouseX > 0 && mouseX < 50 && mouseY > 100 && mouseY < 150) {
        sR = 0
        sG = 0
        sB = 255
    }
    //green button
    else if (mouseIsPressed && mouseX > 0 && mouseX < 50 && mouseY > 50 && mouseY < 100) {
        sR = 0
        sG = 255
        sB = 0 
    } 

    //white
    else if (mouseIsPressed && mouseX > 0 && mouseX < 50 && mouseY > 150 && mouseY < 200) { 
        sR = 255
        sG = 255
        sB = 255
    }
    //black
    else if (mouseIsPressed && mouseX > 0 && mouseX < 50 && mouseY > 200 && mouseY < 250) {
        sG = 0
        sB = 0
        sG = 0
    }
}

function mouseDragged() {
    strokeWeight(10)
    stroke(sR, sG, sB)
    line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY);
}

function keyTyped() {
    if (key == 'e') {
        background(255)
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

If anyone could help that would be great!

Comment: There is a typo in the "black" case. `sG = 0` is twice, but `sR = 0` is missing. So I vote to close this question - off-topic / simple typographical error